# Search XML column referencing DLL namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml

I've been struggling to get a query to return the value of an XML element. The XML contains a few namespaces. The namespace where the tag of interest exists happens to reference a DLL, which i have locally.
I need a query which returns all results where <v:Width> is 15.

```
<ObsFormElementViewModel_Of_string xmlns:m="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Windows.Media" xmlns:v="SXA.FormBuilder.Common.ViewModel" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="SXA.FormBuilder.FormElementGenerator.ViewModels">
  <v:Categories>Observation</v:Categories>
  <v:DataType>FormattedFreeText</v:DataType>
  <v:Height>402</v:Height>
  <v:TabSequence>200</v:TabSequence>
  <v:Width>15</v:Width>
  <v:X>18</v:X>
  <v:Y>101</v:Y>
  <v:ZOrder>2147383648</v:ZOrder>
  <ControlVM>
    <ContainerVM i:type="ObsContainerViewModel">
      <Height>NaN</Height>
      <MaxHeight>9999</MaxHeight>
      <MaxWidth>9999</MaxWidth>
      <Requirements>None</Requirements>
      <Width>NaN</Width>
      <Border />
    </ContainerVM>
    <ContentVM i:type="ObsFormattedFreeTextViewModel">
      <Height>370</Height>
      <MaxHeight>2180</MaxHeight>
      <MaxWidth>2180</MaxWidth>
      <Requirements>None</Requirements>
      <Width>1028</Width>
      <BorderStyle />
      <MaximumInputLength>500</MaximumInputLength>
      <TextStyle>
        <FontNameString>Segoe UI</FontNameString>
        <FontSize>10</FontSize>
      </TextStyle>
    </ContentVM>
    <LabelVM i:type="ObsLabelViewModel">
      <Height>23</Height>
      <MaxHeight>9999</MaxHeight>
      <MaxWidth>9999</MaxWidth>
      <MinHeight>23</MinHeight>
      <MinWidth>14</MinWidth>
      <Requirements>None</Requirements>
      <Width>1028</Width>
      <BorderStyle>
        <LineStyle>NoLine</LineStyle>
      </BorderStyle>
      <LabelWidth>75</LabelWidth>
      <OverrideLabelAs />
      <Text>PF_RTF_Box1</Text>
      <TextStyle>
        <FontNameString>Segoe UI</FontNameString>
        <FontSize>10</FontSize>
      </TextStyle>
    </LabelVM>
    <ObservationName>PF_RTF_Box1</ObservationName>
    <ObservationType>FreeText</ObservationType>
  </ControlVM>
</ObsFormElementViewModel_Of_string>
```

My current query which returns nulls for each row is

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Windows.Media' as m,
'SXA.FormBuilder.Common.ViewModel' as v,
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as x,
'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as i) 

SELECT e.ControlID,
    Y.value('(v:Width)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as Width
FROM SXAFBControl e
OUTER APPLY e.PropertyBagxml.nodes('ObsFormElementViewModel_Of_string') as X(Y)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are five XML namespaces defined in your document:

- xmlns:m="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Windows.Media"
- xmlns:v="SXA.FormBuilder.Common.ViewModel"
- xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
- xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
- xmlns="SXA.FormBuilder.FormElementGenerator.ViewModels"

Take note of that last namespace in particular - it has no prefix defined on it so it is the "default" namespace of the document's root element.

There are only two namespaces required to query the specific value that you're seeking in your question, so the following statement will correctly retrieve that data:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
  default 'SXA.FormBuilder.FormElementGenerator.ViewModels',
  'SXA.FormBuilder.Common.ViewModel' as v
)
SELECT
  e.ControlID,
  Y.value('(v:Width)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as Width
FROM SXAFBControl e
OUTER APPLY e.PropertyBagxml.nodes('/ObsFormElementViewModel_Of_string') as X(Y);
```

One thing to be aware of with XML documents is that the namespace prefixes used (`m`, `v`, `x` and `i`) don't actually matter - they are only unique values to linked the namespace URIs themselves. You can use any set of prefixes in your queries, so long as they map to the correct namespace URIs, so the following statement will also retrieve the same data:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
  'SXA.FormBuilder.FormElementGenerator.ViewModels' as foo,
  'SXA.FormBuilder.Common.ViewModel' as bar
)
SELECT
  e.ControlID,
  Y.value('(bar:Width)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as Width
FROM SXAFBControl e
OUTER APPLY e.PropertyBagxml.nodes('/foo:ObsFormElementViewModel_Of_string') as X(Y);
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me! My use of the same variable names for the namespaces is just my form of OCD :-)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to skip the whole namespace "thing" by doing a a wildcard ns query:

```sql
SELECT e.ControlID,
    Y.value('*:Width[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') as Width
FROM SXAFBControl e
OUTER APPLY e.PropertyBagxml.nodes('*:ObsFormElementViewModel_Of_string') as X(Y)
```

Comment: Yes, you could do that, but that can lead to naming collisions such as common elements named `Width` that belong to different namespaces.

Comment: Yeah, but who mixes that on same level :D

Comment: A fictitious example might include elements `<pixels:Width>` and `<points:Width>`, who's to say?

Comment: Let's hope that OPs xml doesn't do that then :)

Comment: **Bad answer**: A standard mechanism (XML namespaces) is in place in the data to prevent collisions of elements that are identically named but differently defined.  This solution says to completely disregard that mechanism and hope for the best.  Bad idea.  ([@AlwaysLearning is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75703178/290085), and you should have deleted your answer after he [explained the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75702872/search-xml-column-referencing-dll-namespace#comment133553135_75704184).  It's not too late, though.)

Comment: I try to adapt my answer to the actual question of parsing some little thing out of big xml, not to a hypothetical xml academic exercise. It might be useful to someone who can't remember the intricate details of namespace handling. If enough flags / downvotes, i guess it will be deleted soon enough